# Can I have multiple plotlines with Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Simply put I am looking for a way to set two or more plotLines in highcharts/highstocks. The API doccuments do a good job of showing how to set one although I am not sure if there is a way to set two of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, just declare multiple plotLine configurations in the array:

```
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#FF0000',
            width: 2,
            value: 4.5
        }, {
            color: '#00FF00',
            width: 2,
            value: 5.5
        }]
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSREH/)

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple I just couldn't figure it out in my tired state last night. I appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a method where i can supply an array of points to value ? Instead of new tags

> {
>               color: '#00FF00',
>               width: 2,
>               value: 5.5
>           }

for each point  .

Comment: Did you get any answer to your question? I am trying the same thing. Thanks!